# I am unable to delete a file on the Desktop (All Users) but I could delete without the script

Tags: windows, scripting, vbscript, windows-scripting

It crashes on wshShell.Run.

You can see that I run a WScript.Echo and it does print the location of the file name. When I run it, it says the "The system could not find the file specified"

I tried objFile.delete but it says Permission denied. If i perform "del " in the command prompt, it works.

```
For Each objFile In colFiles
   bMatch = objRE.Test(objFile.Name)
   If bMatch Then
      WScript.Echo objFile.Name
      WScript.Echo objFile.Path
        Set wshShell = WScript.CreateObject ("WSCript.shell")
        wshShell.Run "del " & objFile.Path, 1, True     
        Set wshShell = Nothing

   End If
Next
```

Output

```
Lotus Notes 8.5.lnk
C:\Users\Public\Desktop\Lotus Notes 8.5.lnk
(null) (79, 3) : (null)
```

------------------ UPDATE ------------------
The following works perfectly if it's on the Users Desktop (not the AllUsersDesktop). I'm trying to delete it from the AllUsersDesktop

```
For Each objFile In colFiles
   bMatch = objRE.Test(objFile.Name)
   If bMatch Then
     objFile.Delete

   End If
Next
```

---

After applying the following code, I get this error

```
Lotus Notes 8.5.lnk
C:\Users\Public\Desktop\Lotus Notes 8.5.lnk
(null) (81, 3) : (null)
```

Code: (updated as of 5/23)

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
strCurrentDirectory = objShell.SpecialFolders("AllUsersDesktop")
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace(strCurrentDirectory)
Set objFolderItem = objFolder.Self

Set objFolder = objFS.GetFolder(strCurrentDirectory)
Set colFiles = objFolder.Files

Set objRE = New RegExp
objRE.Global     = True
objRE.IgnoreCase = True
objRE.Pattern    = "notes"

For Each objFile In colFiles
   bMatch = objRE.Test(objFile.Name)
   If bMatch Then
      WScript.Echo objFile.Name
      WScript.Echo objFile.Path
        Set wshShell = WScript.CreateObject ("WSCript.shell")
        wshShell.Run "del """ & objFile.Path & """", 1, True  
        Set wshShell = Nothing

   End If
Next
```

Comment: I am testing on Windows 7 but will be deployed for Windows XP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
wshShell.Run "del """ & objFile.Path & """", 1, True
```

Comment: Thanks I copied and pasted your line. Here is the output. (see update in original question)

Answer (score 1):

The path has a space in it, so it should be enclosed in double quotes, something like `"del \"" & objFile.Path & "\""`, or whatever VB syntax for escaping is.

Comment: I tried double " as mentioned on http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=1006042418111 and I've tried single ' as mentioned on http://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=662368 . In both cases, I got the same error ("The system could not find the file specified")